# A label on top of two sub-labels

Tags: html

How to have a top-label on top of two sub-labels where the top-label is not really a label (with validated HTML)?

So basically I need the label NAME on top of FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME.

I have to use  for other code that requires it.

```html
<div id="name">
  <div>
  <div class="input"><label for="first-name">First name</label>
   <input autocomplete="on" class='inp_cont' id="first-name" name="first-name" placeholder="Enter your first name" required="" type="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="input"><label for="last-name">Last name</label>
   <input autocomplete="on" class='inp_cont' id="last-name" name="last-name" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="" type="text"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fieldsets and legends for this. It's the correct valid markup for what you're trying to accomplish.

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Name</legend>
<div class="input">
<label for="first-name">First name</label>
<input autocomplete="on" class='inp_cont' id="first-name" name="first-name" 
placeholder="Enter your first name" required="" type="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="input">
<label for="last-name">Last name</label>
<input autocomplete="on" class='inp_cont' id="last-name" name="last-name" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="" type="text"></div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="name">
<label for="first-name">NAME</label>
  <div>
  <div class="input"><label for="first-name">First name</label>
   <input autocomplete="on" class='inp_cont' id="first-name" name="first-name" placeholder="Enter your first name" required="" type="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="input"><label for="last-name">Last name</label>
   <input autocomplete="on" class='inp_cont' id="last-name" name="last-name" placeholder="Enter your last name" required="" type="text"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```